# Metrizability of infinite product space under box topology

Tags: general-topology

Let $X=[0,1]^\omega$. We know that under the standard product topology, $X$ is metrizable. But is it metrizable under the box topology? My guess is not, and the intuition is that Urysohn's metrization theorem fails because the basis for $X$ under the box topology is uncountable. But that's not sufficient to disprove metrizability.

How can one show that this is indeed the case? (or prove otherwise)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$X$ with the box topology is not even first-countable, which immediately implies it's not metrizable.  To see this, suppose we had a countable neighborhood basis $U_1, U_2, \ldots$ at $(0, 0, \ldots)$.  Then for each $n$, suppose $[0, \epsilon_{n,1}) \times [0, \epsilon_{n,2}) \times \cdots \subseteq U_n$.  Then $V := [0, \frac{1}{2} \epsilon_{1,1}) \times [0, \frac{1}{2} \epsilon_{2,2}) \times \cdots$ is an open neighborhood of $(0, 0, \ldots)$ in the box topology.  However, for each $n$, $(0, 0, \ldots, \frac{3}{4} \epsilon_{n,n}, 0, \ldots)$ (with the nonzero entry at position $n$) is in $U_n$ but not in $V$; so no $U_n$ is contained in $V$.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know metrizability implies first-countable, but reading the proof makes perfect sense.

Comment: Well, just in case, here's the one-line proof of that fact: if $X$ is a metric space and $x \in X$ then the collection of open balls $B_{1/n}(x)$ is a neighborhood basis at $x$.

Answer (score 1):

In the Handbook of Set-theoretic topology (chapter on box products) it is shown that any infinite box product of spaces, that have at least two disjoint open sets (to avoid trivialities) is non-metrisable, in particular not first countable.

Comment: I don't think it's true. Let X be a space with the discrete topology. Then the box topology (on any product) is discrete as well and hence metrizable.

As far as I can tell we need to assume that topology on X is not discrete. Then we proceed with two cases:

(1) X is Hausdorff. The proof is similar to the one by @Daniel Schepler. Just more fun with indices etc.

(2) X is not Hausdorff. This implies that the product is not T2, and hence not metrizable.